# String does not print exact values

Tags: java, android

In android, I have stored many string values in an array list in the format like

```
<ActionItem><Date>03/07/2012</Date><Time>5:23 PM</Time><EstimatedTime>1:00</EstimatedTime><ParticipantList><Participant>part 7</Participant></ParticipantList><Purpose>purp 7</Purpose></ActionItem><ActionItem><Date>03/07/2012</Date><Time>5:23 PM</Time><EstimatedTime>1:00</EstimatedTime><ParticipantList><Participant>part 8</Participant></ParticipantList><Purpose>purp 8</Purpose></ActionItem>
```

In order to append the values in a URL I have converted that array list in to a single string. After the conversion when I append the string value in a URL it returns left with some values from the end:

```
<ActionItem><Date>03/07/2012</Date><Time>5:23 PM</Time><EstimatedTime>1:00</EstimatedTime><ParticipantList><Participant>part 7</Participant></ParticipantList><Purpose>purp 7</Purpose></ActionItem><ActionItem><Da...
```

It seems to work fine when array list has a minimum number of entries like 4 or 5 in array list. But when the entries in array list exceed this, it returns the string like an unexpected form.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you are using Logcat, double click on the end of the **Text** section header to view the full string or you can copy the text and paste it on a text editor to see if you are getting the full URL.

And if you are sending too much data, use **POST** instead of **GET**. Also you may have to check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url).